# How to make functional Validationrequest in Laravel 8 with Mimetypes

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8, mime-types

i have a problem i want to have an showing errormessage if a user uses a false mimetype in the uploadprocess. I cant find the real statement or argument to declare what it should do.

```
        public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'season_name' => 'required|unique:seasons,name',
            'thumbnail' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'season_name.required' => 'Bitte einen Name eingeben!',
            'season_name.unique' => 'Dieser Name ist bereits vorhanden bitte einen anderen wählen!',
   ?--->    'thumbnail.mimes' => 'Bitte eines der folgenden Formate wählen! JPEG, PNG'
        ];
    }
}
```

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Isn't it just `'thumbnails.mimes:jpeg,png'`?

Comment: `'thumbnail.mimes'` should be the right one, what issue or error you are having?

Comment: The problem is its not showing the errormessage, it just accepts it and put it in the database, and also gives me the standard error if the user didnt upload an image.                Edit: seems now its working fine my php storm didnt import the Requestfile it was just a dumb mistake :')